# javascript initialized objects (and the dom)

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

What objects are created initially by compilers(?) of javascript?

I've been learning Io in order to understand prototyping languages. After doing a bit of research I've found the javascript 'Global Object'. What I can't seem to wrap my mind around is where the other built-in functions/prototypes/objects are coming from.

There is a print object and I have no clue where it was created. Was it created by the v8 engine I am using to run the javascript code?

And similarly, I'm a bit confused as to which objects are created in a browser initially. I understand that the browser creates a dom in javascript. For example, the document object. But what other objects are there?

Also, in Io it is possible to view all objects that have been allocated memory. This is accessed through the Lobby. Is there something similar in javascript?

Comment: Are you talking about javascript by itself (e.g. when being used outside a browser)?  Or are you talking about javascript objects in a browser?

Comment: both. I can't find the reference material explaining everything that goes on

Comment: "Everything that goes on" is a big term that means a lot of things.  It sounds like you need to sit down with either a very good reference book on using Javascript in a browser or take a class in it.  This is not something we can easily explain in an SO answer.  My favorite reference for javascript in a browser is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference).

Comment: True. My questions are not pointed. I suppose I was just frustrated with the lack of single comprehensive source of all javascript material. While MDN is sufficient I suppose I was looking for something more, I just checked out some javascript books, I think they will help immensely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite reference on javascript in a browser, global objects and DOM objects is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference).

The browser creates a whole bunch of objects and makes them available for javascript access.  They are created by the browser (not by the javascript engine as they aren't officially part of javascript), but the browser makes them accessible from javascript.

For example, the browser creates a `document` object, a `window` object which serves as the `global object` in the browser and adds a whole bunch of properties to the `window` object.

You can see a list of enumerable properties on the `window` object in your particular browser from this sample app: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nh39F/

Javascript, by itself, has some objects is creates just for it's own management of functionality.  For example, there is usually a `Math` object that contains a bunch of math methods and a Date object that contains a bunch of date functionality.